# Converting a free variable in a pure function into a parameter that can be varied under iteration

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

Here I am going, as a matter of illustration, make a large string list:

```
l = Characters[WordList[]];
l = Table[DeleteDuplicates[l[[i]]], {i, Length[l]}];
```

This list would give all English words disjointed by letters. 
Now I want have a function that takes most frequent letter and join them into capital letter. k is the symbol for that for example k=2 takes two most frequent letters, k=3 takes 3 most frequent letters and so on.

Now I want to select from l those elements that are size 8, once with k=2 in the next step I want to look at the second part of the new list and make k=3 and so on. Here is what I did:

```
k = 2;
ClearAll[replace]
replace = 
  With[{commonest = 
      Commonest[Flatten[Map[Subsets[#, {k}] &, #], 1]][[
       1]]}, # //. {OrderlessPatternSequence[## & @@ commonest, 
        p___]} :> {StringJoin[ToUpperCase[commonest]], p}] &;
a1 = NestList[replace, Select[l, Length@# == 8 &], 1];
k = 3;
ClearAll[replace]
replace = 
  With[{commonest = 
      Commonest[
        Flatten[Map[Subsets[#, {k}] &, #], 
         1]][[1]]}, # //. {OrderlessPatternSequence[## & @@ commonest,
         p___]} :> {StringJoin[ToUpperCase[commonest]], p}] &;
a2 = NestList[replace, Select[a1[[2]], Length@# == 8 &], 1];
k = 4;
ClearAll[replace]
replace = 
  With[{commonest = 
      Commonest[
        Flatten[Map[Subsets[#, {k}] &, #], 
         1]][[1]]}, # //. {OrderlessPatternSequence[## & @@ commonest,
         p___]} :> {StringJoin[ToUpperCase[commonest]], p}] &;
a3 = NestList[replace, Select[a2[[2]], Length@# == 8 &], 1];
```

I wonder how can I do this operation meaning make a1, a2 and a3 lists without re-writting the replace function every time. As you can see a1 looks at l, and a2 looks at a1 and so on (in `a1 = NestList[replace, Select[l, Length@# == 8 &], 1]`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by defining `replace` as function that returns a replacer based on `k` and using `FoldList` in place of `Nest`.

But first I advise speeding things up by preprocessing the data.

```
data =
  Select[DeleteDuplicates /@ Characters[WordList[]], Length @ # == 8 &] //
    DeleteDuplicates;
```

This reduces the number characters processed down to 52416 from the 274098 in your list `l`.

Now here how is it works with `FoldList` and a parameratized  `replace`.

```
replace[k_] := 
  With[{commonest = Commonest[Flatten[Map[Subsets[#, {k}] &, #], 1]][[1]]}, 
     # //. {OrderlessPatternSequence[## & @@ commonest, p___]} :> 
             {StringJoin[ToUpperCase[commonest]], p}] &;
k = 3; u = FoldList[replace[#2][#1] &, data, Range[2, k]];
Row[Column /@ u[[All, ;; 12]]]
```

[image: results]

The variable `u` is of course bound to the full results, but to keep this answer down to a reasonable length, I have chosen to show only the 1st 12 items in each sublist of the full output.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function `f` that generates your function like this:

```
f = k \[Function] 
   With[{commonest = 
       Commonest[
         Flatten[Map[Subsets[#, {k}] &, #], 
          1]][[1]]}, # //. {OrderlessPatternSequence[## & @@ 
          commonest, p___]} :> {StringJoin[ToUpperCase[commonest]], 
        p}] &;
```

And then

```
a1 = NestList[f[2], Select[l, Length@# == 8 &], 1];
a2 = NestList[f[3], Select[a1[[2]], Length@# == 8 &], 1];
a3 = NestList[f[4], Select[a2[[2]], Length@# == 8 &], 1];
```